# "Exceeded maximum execution time in Google Apps Script" stops my script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am worknig on one project using google sheets and I need to create one Script using google Apps Script.

I need to rewrite every row in sheet, that contain certain number. 
I have following code now:

```
function AddDuplicate() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ActiveSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  //var data = sheet.getDataRange().getRow();

  var Zdroj = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ZDROJ");
  var Vysledek = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("VYSLEDKY");
  var PocetRadkuVysledku = 1;
  for(var i= AktualniPoziceY ;i<500;i++)
  {
    var pocet = Zdroj.getRange(i,7).getValue();
   for(var y = 1; y<pocet+1;y++)
     {
     for(var o = AktualniPoziceX ; o < 10; o++)
       {
         var Pom = Zdroj.getRange(i,o).getValue();
         Vysledek.getRange(PocetRadkuVysledku, o).setValue(Pom);
        }
        PocetRadkuVysledku++;
     }
   }
}
```

It works, but only problem I got is "Exceeded maximum execution time in Google Apps Script" error, that will stop my script on some point. Can someone help, how to overcome this?

Comment: Have you reviewed similar questions? Have you reviewed best practices? See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

### The reason you exceed maximum execution time is that your code is slow, see [Apps Script Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

How to apply it to your case:

Rather than retrieving a range and setting values within each iteration of a nested for loop (which is inefficient due to the multiple calls to the SpreadsheetApp service), use arrays and make only one call after finishing the iteration.

Use `getValues()` and `setValues()` instead of `getValue()` and `setValue()`.

Sample (you mind need to adapt the [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) dimensions to your needs, what is important is that the destination range has the same amount of rows and columns as the original one):

```
function AddDuplicate() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActive();
  var Zdroj = ss.getSheetByName("ZDROJ");
  var Vysledek = ss.getSheetByName("VYSLEDKY");
  var pocetArray = Zdroj.getRange(1,7, 500, 1).getValues();   
  Vysledek.getRange(1, AktualniPoziceX, pocet, 500, 1).setValues(pocetArray);
 }
```